# display multiple data from database to multiple input box

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have this problem where I want to display multiple values to multiple input boxes depending on how many the value is. I have already a code but the problem is it is only displaying the value in one input box. I will show you the code.

Here is the database:

```
attId   attSubject        attDate     docId
------  ----------------- ----------  ------
     1  FAAS FRONT & BACK 2018-01-25      36
     2  NOA & TAX BILL    2018-09-12      36
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="attchecklist" name="attchecklist">
```

Javascript code:

```
$("#num").val(mydata.docId);
var docIdChecklist = $("#num").val();
$("#attchecklist").load('php/getAttachmentForChecklist.php',
     {docIdChecklist:docIdChecklist},
      function(data) {
          $("#attchecklist").val(data);
      }
 );
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
require_once('../kclass/kconnect.php');
require_once('../common.php');
session_name(xevPRJ);
session_start();
$response= new kconnect();
$response->DB = $_SESSION['sys'];
$docIdChecklist = $_POST['docIdChecklist'];

$response->setCon();


$sqlx = "SELECT attSubject from `attachment` WHERE ((docId = '$docIdChecklist') AND (is_deleted = 0))";
$resultx=$response->kMysqli->query($sqlx);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultx, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $attSubject = $row['attSubject'];

        echo $attSubject;

    }

$response->unsetCon();
?>
```

and here is the result:

[image: Result Image]

I want the result to be separated in input boxes. How to achieve this?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your codes on the frontend part (the input field)

Comment: it's in the html code part

Comment: I am hoping to see a little bit more of the codes. But nevermind, I'll give an idea on how to do it.

You can actually loop the html part using php. So you'll get more input based on your data (assuming you are using PHP front-end)

Otherwise, you can use ```.append()``` function to include html content into your form/div

Comment: I'm curious, is what's defined in this a pre-defined constant? `session_name(xevPRJ);`. If not, then it should be quoted. See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNinerthe pre-defined constant is not really important in this question

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria can you show me how?

Comment: @Rak put a space after my member name. I never got the ping and was still in the question but I have now left, so no need to reping. So who was I / were we to know? Again, no need to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your div something like this

```
<div id="myDiv></div>
```

Then you can append your form using JS

```
...
$("#attchecklist").load('php/getAttachmentForChecklist.php',
    {docIdChecklist:docIdChecklist},
    function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            $("#myDiv").append(`<input type="text" id="attchecklist${index}" name="attchecklist${index}" value="${value}">`)
        });
    }
);
```

However, you are expected to return JSON array of data, instead of just echo the data on PHP API. Something like this:

```
$result = [];
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultx, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    array_push($result, $row['attSubject']);
}

$response->unsetCon();
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: my input box has no form, I just want to display the data from the database.

Comment: Then change to div instead

Comment: already tried that still not working, not displaying the result.

Comment: I'm receiving error in `$result [];`. ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' `.

Comment: I have another problem, the result is still in json format

Comment: $result []; Make sure to put ```=``` sign.

Comment: I already solved that problem. I have another problem, the result is still in json format.

Comment: Now i have another problem, each character is has one input box, the result contains many input boxes because each of the char has one input box. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you open new issue instead and send the url here. If this question is answered, marked it first so everyone else can learn step by step.

Comment: here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52585447/display-json-encode-result-to-input-tag-in-html)