# display json_encode result to input tag in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have this problem where I want to display the json result in input tag. I tried this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583662/display-multiple-data-from-database-to-multiple-input-box) but the result is incorrect.

This is the json data:

```
["FAAS FRONT & BACK","NOA & TAX BILL"]
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

As you can see each character is in input box. How can I solve this?

The result should be like this:

[image: This should be the result]

Comment: You need to parse the data first :  JSON.parse(json_data)

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: here is a jsfiddle which does the same for your json. https://jsfiddle.net/keuf94xj/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the JS, try use

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

So you can use it as an object instead.